# switch case not working in scroll function in jquery

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I created jquery code for scroll website .it's worked but everytime it give default value of swich case.

This is my html code

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" id="skills">Skills</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" id="project">project</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" id="contact">contact</a>
</li>
```

This is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var value_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var scrolledheight = 2500;
        var pix = 'px';
        alert(value_id);
        var heightvalue = scrolledheight + pix;
        switch (value_id) {
            case about:
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: heightvalue
                }, 600);
                break;
            case skills:
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: heightvalue
                }, 600);
                break;
            case project:
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $(window).height()
                }, 600);
                alert("project");
                break;
            default:
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $(window).height()
                }, 600);
                alert("contact");

                return false;
        }
    });
});
```

someone know how to fix this one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the cases to match strings:

```
case 'about':
case 'skills':
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Since the case [*expression*] is a string, put it in quotes.

Eg: case "about":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 0):

the variable is undefined .changed variable to string

```
    switch(value_id) {
case "about":
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: heightvalue}, 600);
      break;
case "skills":
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: heightvalue}, 600);
      break;
case "project":
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window).height()}, 600);
             alert("project"); 
    break;
default:
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window).height()}, 600);
         alert("contact"); 

    return false;
}
```

Comment: i checked that id is coming dynamically not default ,i think your animate code is not working. is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use string :

```
...
    case "about":
...
```